# vue reactivity not working until something in the dom updates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I don't know how to describe this correctly, as I've just begun learning Vue. However I've come across quite a strange bug(at least I think so.) as the reactivity won't work.

The objects are registered (pulled in with axios) but isn't shown until I change something in the one of the registered objects, in this case a input field bound to a vue model. I've checked for other posts describing this issue, but can't come across any.

This is what spits out the messages:

```
<li v-for="message in currentConversation.messages">{{ message.body }}</li>
```

And this is what is setting/getting the messages:

```
axios
    .get("/api/messenger/conversation/messages/" + conversation.id)
    .then(response => {
      this.currentConversation.messages = response.data.reverse();
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });

  if (window.Echo) {
    this.listenForMessages(conversation.id);
  }
```

Anyone with similar experiences, who could point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: This sort of thing *usually* indicates that what you are updating was not reactive (`messages` was not declared as part of the `data` statement, for example). It is hard to say, without much code to look at. I'm sure there's a lot of code, but if you can  start taking out everything that's not directly related to what you're looking for, maybe you will get to the point that it works or is small enough to post here.

Comment: @RoyJ It is reactive, however. That what's weird. It's defined in the data function, and if I post a new message, and push it to the object array, the reactivity works.. But yeah, I get what you're saying about the code, I'll try to see if I can get it to reproduce without posting all 600 lines of code. Thanks!

Comment: Is there maybe a `v-for` that doesn't have a `:key` attribute?

Comment: @RoyJ Yeah, the list is missing `:key`. `<li v-for="message in currentConversation.messages">{{ message.body }}</li>`

Comment: I wish, but all have keys. However after some poking about I've found out that if I hardwire the conversations object instead of doing this `this.conversations = response.data.reverse();` it works. It's the same data, though.. Any ideas?

Comment: Or rather, even if I add keys, it doesn't work. It's true that there was no key for currentConversation.messages

Comment: It happened to me. I replaced the way that `data` function was defined. I was using arrow function until I replaced by conventional `return` and it worked.